# Node: Module parse failed: Unexpected token "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type"

Tags: node.js, webpack

This is in my webpack.base.conf.js

```
resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
            alias: {
                'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
                '@': resolve('src'),
            }
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
                    loader: 'eslint-loader',
                    enforce: 'pre',
                    include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
                    options: {
                        formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    loader: 'vue-loader',
                    options: vueLoaderConfig
                },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
                },
```

When I run webpack using this line

```
webpack ./src/main.js --output ./dist
```

Here is the full error:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.js 240:36
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (240:36)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|                 state.connection.lastUpdate = Date.now();
|
>                 state.currencies = {...information.currenciesInfo};
|
|                 state.trends = {...information.trends};
```

On some other site I read it may have to do with webpack or some enclosure issues. Does anyone spot an obvious issue?

I believe the programmer used webpack3 and I built webpack4 from scratch

Input appreciated

Edit: The main.js

```
// information = information[0];
                state.connection.lastUpdate = Date.now();

                state.currencies = {...information.currenciesInfo};

                state.trends = {...information.trends};
```

Comment: what is your babelrc config? do you have other presets set to babel-loader?

Comment: {
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
      }
    }],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx", "transform-runtime"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["env", "stage-2"],
      "plugins": ["istanbul"]
    }
  }
}

Comment: you need preset for spread operator

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Spread operator what is that? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need a plugin to transform spread operator (...).

Use https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread